# How to use arrays in webassembly?

Tags: webassembly

I compile C program into wasm using the website

https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/.

Whenever i try to create an array in webassembly and use it, i get a "TypeError: index out of bounds" when i run the program. I am using an alternative solution for the momentand succeed to run the program.

The solution that works : passing an array as parameter ( pointer )

```
int prime(int array[], int n) {


  for (int x=0; x<n; x++) {
    array[x] = 1;
  }

  int count = 0;  

  for(int i=2; i<n; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
      count += 1;
      for (int j=2*i; j<n; j+=i){
        array[j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

After importing the `prime.wasm` file in javascript i have to call the function like this:

`console.log(prime(0, 100));`

and what i would like to have (create an array in my wasm function) :

```
int prime(int n) {

  bool array[n];

  for (int x=0; x<n; x++) {
    array[x] = true;
  }


  int count = 0;  


  for(int i=2; i<n; i++) {
    if (array[i] == true) {
      count += 1;
      for (int j=2*i; j<n; j+=i){
        array[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

After importing the wasm file in javascript i would like to call the function like this:

`console.log(prime(100));`

How can i solve this problem and finally use arrays inside wasm function without having to pass any pointers ?